# Can I predict the value of Pi(3.14) using a random number function generated from scratch?

Tags: python, numpy, random, predict, pi

I have tried to predict the value of Pi using a random function generated from scratch. But it is giving an output of 4 instead of 3.14.My code for predicting Pi works perfectly when I'm using "np.random.uniform" instead of my random function.How can I improve my random function so that I can get an output of 3.14?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#random function using linear congruent generator
def generate_rand(mult=16807,mod=(2**31)-1, seed=123456789, size=1):
    U = np.zeros(size)
    X = (seed*mult+1)%mod 
    U[0] = X/mod 
    for i in range(1, size):
        X = (X*mult+1)%mod
        U[i] = X/mod 
    return U
def generate_random(low=0,high=1, seed=123456789, size=1):
#Generates uniformly random number between 'low' and 'high' limits
    return low+(high-low) *generate_rand(seed=seed, size=size)
def pi_estimator(samples):
    points_inside_circle= 0
    total_num_points = 0

    for _ in range(samples):
        x = generate_random()
        y = generate_random()
        distance = x**2 + y**2
        if distance <= 1:
            points_inside_circle +=1
        total_num_points += 1
    return 4* points_inside_circle/total_num_points
pi_estimator(10000)
```

Comment: You could remove the "calculating pi" part and reduce your question to "*how to create a uniform random number generator?*" ;)

Comment: @mozway OP has a (well-known but poor by modern standards) random number generator.  The problem isn’t with implementing it, it’s with using it correctly.

Comment: @pjs I hadn't checked the details, obviously if the seed is hardcoded that makes is not a PRNG :p

Comment: @mozway A default seed is hard-coded, but you can override that with any seed you want. It’s a legit PRNG known as [MINSTD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmer_random_number_generator#Parameters_in_common_use).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your numbers aren't actually random. You're asking for one random number giving the same "seed" so you always getting the same number.

You need to either have your `generate_rand` be a class saving the "seed" and using the last number as "seed" or ask for all the numbers at once.  I decided for the 2nd approach

```
def pi_estimator(samples):
    points_inside_circle= 0
    total_num_points = 0
    X,Y = generate_rand(size=2*samples).reshape(2,-1)

    for x,y in zip(X,Y):
        distance = x**2 + y**2
        if distance <= 1:
            points_inside_circle +=1
        total_num_points += 1
    return 4* points_inside_circle/total_num_points
```

Now `pi_estimator(10**7)` gives `3.1418544` which looks like `pi` to me.